# How to prevent browser (firefox) from downloading embed src each time it shows?

Tags: jquery, flash, embed, show

I've got embed tag in my slider to display flash animation. Browser downloads swf file each time it's beeing shown (src attribute does not change). images in this slider are being got only once, while embed object every time.

Do you have any idea how to stop this downloading?

Comment: You should check what HTTP headers are coming back when SWF is downloaded. It may have Cache header (Cache-control) set to "no cache".

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on Cache-Control HTTP header returned from the server when you SWF file is downloaded. If the header is as follows: `Cache-Control:max-age=900` that means the resource will be cached for 900 seconds in your browser. If the header is `Cache-Control:max-age=0` that means no caching and the resource will be downloaded every time you request the page.

You can check Cache-Control header using Firefox Firebug (example of SWF request from Adobe website)

[image]

**EDIT**

If you notice that `Cache-Control` is set to `max-age=0` then you would have to change configuration on the server. There is no much you can do about it from browser point of view. Also you should see `Cache-Control` header set for your images; you can compare their values.

Comment: The swf file is cached and it's being loaded from cache but the problem are requests for the file each time I show embed tag. You can hide() and show() img tag and browser wont download image file each time element is being shown. In contrary each time slider shows embed element browser requests the src file.

Comment: the request will always be shown, even when loaded from cache... look deeper to check where it is loaded from.

Comment: And what does Firebug says about that request? Does it have response code 200 or does it say "from cache"?

Comment: Would you be able to share Firebug Net tab with all the requests please? That would give us better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to what Tom shared, you should also check if you are looking at the correct parameter.

If you were perhaps looking at get request, do ensure it is not '**not modified**':

[image]

If it is, then you need not worry, It is from cache.

The browser handles the redundant request & loads it from cache.